# Is it possible to use ReorderableListView in a "wrapping" mode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like the `ReorderableListView` not to take up the whole height which is given to it, but to be as tall as the item views that it contains.

I could make the list either flex and **fill the whole height** it is given, or put it in a SizedBox and have a **fixed height**.

I'd like to add an `+ Add` list tile directly under the list items (similar to Google Keep on Android)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
Wrap your `List` with an `Expanded` widget. 
Fetch the number of items in your list and return the `Add` List tile widget at the `length-1` position of your list. 
You can alter the size of your ListView in correlation to the number of items fetched from the list. 
`Expanded` will help you alter the length dynamically.
eg:

```dart
Expanded(
    child: new ListView.builder
      (
        itemCount: litems.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
          return new Text(litems[Index]);

           if(length==length-1){
            //**call your Add List tile widget here**
            }
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply!
Issue is: I want this behavior with the ReorderableListView, which is in fact a SingleChildScrollView which contains a Column. 
Also I don't want the `Add` to be reorderable, so in that sense it should not be part of the list

Comment: Could you share the code of your ReorderableListView?